# Pip install Proxy with 403 Forbidden inside of a Dockerfile

Tags: python, linux, docker, proxy, rhel

I am trying to set up a docker container by using a Dockerfile that is inside of a corporate network behind a proxy.

Each time I am trying to execute the installation of different python packages by running the "pip install" command I am facing the following issue:

```
Step 9/20 : RUN pip install requests

---> Running in 98d679800849

Collecting requests

  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))
```

My current Dockerfile contains the following commands:

```
# Base image

FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV http_proxy http://user:pw@server:port/
ENV https_proxy http://user:pw@server:port/
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://user:pw@server:port/
ENV HTTPS_PROXY http://user:pw@server:port/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip #thats working
RUN pip install requests #not working
RUN pip --proxy=http://user:pw@server:port/ install pandas #not working either
```

I tried several solutions like providing the build argument when executing the build command and passing the proxy settings inside for example. I dont have further clues why its not working for the running the **pip command**.
Thats even more strange since I am able to pull the base image which had not worked before defining the proxysettings by using the ENV variable. Anyone here that has a clue what causes this problem?

Comment: You could try adding internal DNS server into `resolve.conf` inside a container. You can do it by a command `docker run --dns=x.x.x.x image bash` and then trying to run `pip install`. --dns sets custom DNS server inside a container.

Comment: is this for the run or the build command? Currently I am facing that issue while building the container

Comment: It's for the `run` command, for testing purposes I'd remove all `pip install` commands from the Dockerfile and I'd try to test it inside a container by running commands manually.